# For a unique field 1, collapse non-unique entries in another field

Tags: linux, r, bash, while-loop

I have a data set which is a left outer join intersection of two data sets. I now have multiple entries from the first data set for each overlap with the second. Just note that Assembly.1000 repeats three times and I want to collapse that into 1

```
Assembly.1000 chrX 560000 575000 ABC1   20
Assembly.1000 chrX 560000 575000 IL15RA 3.2
Assembly.1000 chrX 560000 575000 BRCA1  20
Assembly.1038 chrX 780000 829000 .      .
Assembly.1338 chrX 960000 999000 ACTIN  3800
Assembly.1338 chrX 960000 999000 ACTIN  4000
```

As you can see the File 1 entry for Assembly.1000 is repeated three times, for each File 2 entry (ABC1, IL15RA, BRCA1)

What I would like to parse the output to

```
Assembly.1000 chrX 560000 575000 ABC1;IL15RA;BRCA1   20;3.2;20
Assembly.1038 chrX 780000 829000 .      .
Assembly.1338 chrX 960000 999000 ACTIN,ACTIN 3800;4000
```

I can accomplish this with $ while read command and looking at previous entries in the loop but for large files (~1e6 entries) this simply is not efficient enough. Does anyone have any suggestions in ways to program this efficiently?

Comment: See `aggregate` or check out the "data.table" package and aggregate the columns with `paste`. But that ultimately makes your data pretty hard to work with later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", as defined below:

```
mydf <- structure(list(V1 = c("Assembly.1000", "Assembly.1000", 
    "Assembly.1000", "Assembly.1038", "Assembly.1338", "Assembly.1338"), 
    V2 = c("chrX", "chrX", "chrX", "chrX", "chrX", "chrX"), 
    V3 = c(560000L, 560000L, 560000L, 780000L, 960000L, 960000L), 
    V4 = c(575000L, 575000L, 575000L, 829000L, 999000L, 999000L), 
    V5 = c("ABC1", "IL15RA", "BRCA1", ".", "ACTIN", "ACTIN"), 
    V6 = c("20", "3.2", "20", ".", "3800", "4000")), 
    .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
mydf
#              V1   V2     V3     V4     V5   V6
# 1 Assembly.1000 chrX 560000 575000   ABC1   20
# 2 Assembly.1000 chrX 560000 575000 IL15RA  3.2
# 3 Assembly.1000 chrX 560000 575000  BRCA1   20
# 4 Assembly.1038 chrX 780000 829000      .    .
# 5 Assembly.1338 chrX 960000 999000  ACTIN 3800
# 6 Assembly.1338 chrX 960000 999000  ACTIN 4000
```

Here's the `aggregate` approach:

```
aggregate(cbind(V5, V6) ~ ., mydf, paste, collapse = "; ")
#              V1   V2     V3     V4                  V5          V6
# 1 Assembly.1000 chrX 560000 575000 ABC1; IL15RA; BRCA1 20; 3.2; 20
# 2 Assembly.1038 chrX 780000 829000                   .           .
# 3 Assembly.1338 chrX 960000 999000        ACTIN; ACTIN  3800; 4000
```

Here's the "data.table" approach, using the same "mydf" as a starting point:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = "; "), by = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")]
#               V1   V2     V3     V4                  V5          V6
# 1: Assembly.1000 chrX 560000 575000 ABC1; IL15RA; BRCA1 20; 3.2; 20
# 2: Assembly.1038 chrX 780000 829000                   .           .
# 3: Assembly.1338 chrX 960000 999000        ACTIN; ACTIN  3800; 4000
```

Comment: +1 because this should work irrespective of the number of columns that the concatenation needs to be performed on.

Comment: @Codoremifa, I think it's interesting that what we need to specify in the base R approach and the data.table approach are different.

Comment: You mean like V5, and V6 as compared to V1 - V4? That way, the base R approach looks easier to write when the "by" columns are a very large number whereas the data.table approach looks easier when there are a large number of columns to concatenate. But you're right, it's interesting how they work this way.

Comment: @Codoremifa, yes. When there are a large number of columns involved, though, I tend to use `setdiff` in some way to help and to make it less error-prone to typing mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much this works but could you explain **cbind(V5, V6) ~ .** I don't think I understand that.

Comment: @Artem, the `cbind(V5, V6) ~ .` part means to aggregate the values found in variable "V5" and in variable "V6" grouped by all other columns as "id" or "key" variables. Does that make sense? Alternatively, in this example, it can be written as `cbind(V5, V6) ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4`, so the use of `.` is sort of a shorthand approach that can be used with the `aggregate` function. See `?aggregate` for more details.

Comment: @Ananda thanks, I think I understand it and after playing around with it I think I understand how aggregate works. And I RTFM :)

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table as per @AnandaMahto's suggestion but with a slightly simpler syntax.

```
library(data.table)

dataset <- data.table(
   a1 = c(1,1,3,3,5,5),
   b1 = c(1,1,3,3,5,5),
   c1 = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),
   d1 = c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
)

dataset2 <- dataset[,
   list(
      c1d1 = paste(c1,d1, sep = "", collapse = "")
      d1 = paste(d1, collapse = ""),
      c1 = paste(c1, collapse = "")
   ),
   by = c("a1","b1")
]


#> dataset
#   a1 b1 c1 d1
#1:  1  1  a  a
#2:  1  1  b  b
#3:  3  3  c  c
#4:  3  3  d  d
#5:  5  5  e  e
#6:  5  5  f  f
#> dataset2
#   a1 b1 c1d1 d1 c1
#1:  1  1 aabb ab ab
#2:  3  3 ccdd cd cd
#3:  5  5 eeff ef ef
```

Comment: That puts everything from `c1` and `d1` into a *single* column. I'm not sure that this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Added the other option as well.

Comment: Haha, you sly dog you. :)